# Xorg keeps throwing series of errors

Tags: linux, x11, archlinux, xorg

Currently running: Arch linux 4.0.7-2

I've worked with X11 for a while without any trouble. Until recently after a reboot the following error came up: `No screens found`. I looked up similar questions but none of them had the answer required. I tried to remake my configuration file but that wasn't possible either due to `Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed.`
I spend hours trying to find a fix but nothing worked, I tried re-installing every single package I had and removed everything to bare. Unfortunately no luck.

I then went and reinstalled entire Arch linux but to my surprise the first error to appear when trying to make a configuration file was `No devices to configure`. Running `startx` however gives me a set of floating terminals but freezes entirely.

`lspci -vvv` http://ix.io/juQ

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` http://ix.io/juR

I'm kind of clueless right now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whomever down votes could care to explain it?

Comment: I think that this question should be asked in another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is  located in that line of your log:

```
[   355.070] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/i740_drv.so
[   355.079] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/i740_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/i740_drv.so: undefined symbol: I740_Sync
```

It seems that this file is missing, googling a little i found that archlinux forum post, that probably will help you:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176555

What you need to do, is simply run that command:

```
pacman -Sf `pacman -Qqet`
```

And maybe it solve the problem (there are no more answers to that post, so i'm not sure if it works)

Comment: The -f flag is non existent unfortunately. I did on the other side remove the i740 driver as I am fairly sure it is not used, I didn't use it before and only Installed it in the hope that it might help (which it didn't). So this took care of that error. On the other hand still no success. PS. I really appreciate your effort.